# Wordpress Manually adding data Via Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am adding data to the wordpress with sql.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO idiot_posts (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, 
    `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES 
    ('', '2', now(), now(), '', 'placeholder', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'closed', '', 'placeholder', '', '', '', '', '', $icerikid, '$newname', '0', 'attachment', 'image/jpeg', '0')";
    mysql_query($sql, $baglanti);
    $kapakid = mysql_insert_id();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO idiot_postmeta (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('', $icerikid, '_thumbnail_id', $kapakid)";
    mysql_query($sql, $baglanti);
    echo mysql_error();
```

These are my codes. I add the data. But featured image does not come. I'm waiting for your help

Thank you from now.

Comment: How are `idiot_posts` distinguished from non-idiot posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first create a post meta record in `idiot_postmeta`, like this:

`INSERT INTO idiot_postmeta (meta_value, meta_key, post_id) VALUES ('".$file_name."', '_wp_attached_file',".$attachment_id.");`

Where $attachment_id is the post id of the attachment post you created in your first query

And only after this, you should run your last query which only identifies the attachment post as the thumbnail for the post -

`` $sql = "INSERT INTO idiot_postmeta (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('', $icerikid, '_thumbnail_id', $kapakid)"; ``